# Unix Commands Question/Book Recommendations

Tags: linux, unix, programming-languages

Ok this is a 2 parter.
First of all, this may sound stupid, but are all Unix Commands on Linux Distros? Does any Linux Distro add any.

And commands like....pwd or......ssh, like what are these "written" in programming language wise. C?

Second part, What is a good book that lists and explains all the Unix commands (or at least most of them)

thanks

Comment: Not programming related. Should be moved to superuser.

Comment: How is asking what the different commands are written in language wise NOT program related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not all linux distributions come with one and the same set of commands. There is, however, The Single UNIX® Specification, which lists [canonical commands and utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcuix.html).
2. In short: The majority of programs is written in C.
3. Again, take a look at [The Single UNIX® Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/) to get an overview. Once you have opened a terminal with a shell, just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> - this will yield a list of commands on your machine.

   $ # press 
   Display all 3358 possibilities? (y or n)

Most commands have man pages, too, if you want to know more about them.

```
 $ man pwd
```

Comment: Ah I see the canonical set of commands is the original Unix commands list?

Answer (score 4):

1. The biggest difference you will find
   between the Unix (and its
   derivatives) and Linux commands are
   the *options* that exist for those
   commands.  Specifically, the GNU
   versions tend to add more
   functionality to their commands but
   their use is not portable to non-GNU
   systems like BSD or Unix.

   A common example of this would be
   the GNU `sed -i` option which allows
   you to do an in-place edit on the
   file.  Non-GNU versions of sed
   require you to first write to a temp
   file then copy the temp file over
   the original.

   In order to help define what is
   portable code and what is not, there
   are the
   [**POSIX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix)
   and
   [**SUS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)
   specifications.  Any shell which
   claims to be POSIX compliant
   guarantees that any code written
   against the POSIX standard will
   perform identically. The `bash`
   shell is a POSIX compliant shell but
   that doesn't mean *all* bash
   commands are POSIX compliant.
2. For your second question, yes, most
   commands in *binary* form were
   written in the C language. 
   Sometimes you'll find certain
   commands that are written in
   scripting languages such as `perl`,
   `python` or `bash`.  The `rename`
   command is one example that exists
   in both `perl` and binary form
   written from C.
3. For your 3rd question on Book
   Recommendations, see [**this SO
   question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802309/shell-scripting-book)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think it would be better to refer to [shells](http://tinyurl.com/yyacx8) here, since each *nix distro can come with numerous shells. To answer your questions:

1. Many commands are available on all shells, but of course each shell can add their own commands. Additionally, many programs can add their own shell accessible programs.
2. I found the [O'Reilly book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009656) on learning unix shells to be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Yes / C. 2. O'Reilly, and Apress

---

***I. Common Commands***

There is a core set of commands that true Unix and all of the Linux distros have.

For some time, the distributions have been evolving to install a set of packages, and since there are thousands and thousands to choose from, the idea of a "*base system*" has given way to that of a "*default install*".  For example, some can be installed without X or graphics.

Some of the original Unix commands or rewrites of them are available with BSD licenses, and you will run into many of those on true Unix, *BSD, and on the Mac.  There are also a set of GPL-licensed rewrites of the Unix commands.  These tend to be quite elaborate, leading to confusing manpages, but sometimes they are considerably more useful than the original Unix program. Groff is a good example of a case where the original code has been completely superseded. In any case, Linux distros stick as much as possible to the GPL/GNU versions.

*Language:* The core commands are almost entirely written in C.  As the C++ and C compilers have merged, a few packages are written in C++. A few are written in Posix shell code. As the distributions have grown in scope and size, more packages that are included are written in languages like Perl and Python. I presume you may see packages written in Ruby as well. (Ruby comes with the Mac now.)

***II. Books***

O'Reilly and Apress are two good sources for Unix and Linux publications.

---

***III.*** Well, there wasn't a ***III*** but Mac OS X is built on a version of Unix. You can learn Unix perfectly well in the Terminal app on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I learned much of the basics from http://linuxcommand.org/. Maybe that will help you and the price is right

And visiting it just now I see that the author has compiled it into book for free under a CC licence. Check out the description and a download link [here](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php).